# Why is Green's theorem a special case of Stokes theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

I have already seen related questions and don't understand. Please help me.

$\oint_C \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = \iint_S (\nabla x \mathbf{A})\cdot \mathbf{n}$ dS

Let $A \leq P,Q,0>$

Then $\nabla x \mathbf{A}= <0,0,(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} )>$.

So
$\iint_S (\nabla x \mathbf{A})\cdot \mathbf{n}$  dS $=\iint_S <0,0,(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} )>\cdot \mathbf{n}$ dS $=\iint_S <0,0,(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} )>\cdot \mathbf{k}$ dS$=\iint_S (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} )$ dS

Now, here people replace dS with dA and then say its equal to green's theorem but why would be able to do that?
Isn't
dS =$|r_u x r_v|$ dA

Please see screenshot

> [image]

or this second screenshot. Why do we take unit normal vector. We don't do that when going from dS to dA as seen in this screenshot.

> [image]

in this third screenshot, Wikipedia does it but doesn't explain the step I struggle with.
[image]

Comment: Surely not answering your question in a way that's immediately satisfying to you, but, still, is a sort of "larger" answer: the general pattern of (generalized) Stokes' theorem is that (in tersest notation) $\int_{\partial D} \omega = \int_D d\omega$, where $\partial D$ is the boundary of a domain $D$, and $d\omega$ is the exterior derivative of the differential form $\omega$. Explanation of the latter concept is both an explanation of why the concept is correct, and of how to prove such a thing. In any case, both classical Green's and other similarly things can be understood as examples. :)

Comment: On a surface inside the $xy$ plane you can use $\mathbf{r}=\langle x,y,0 \rangle$ and compute that $|\mathbf{r}_x \times \mathbf{r}_y|=1$ so $dS=dA$ (this is the scalar $dS$ not the vector $dS$). (Similarly you can use $\mathbf{r}=\langle x,y,z_0 \rangle$ for a surface in the plane $z=z_0$). Let me know whether this completely answers your question, if it does then I will post it as an answer.

Comment: oh ok ty guys. I think I understand a bit better. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't going crazy. I will accept the answer of anyone who makes an answer because I think I get it thanks to you guys.

Comment: What Ian said; the form including $|\mathbf{r}_x \times \mathbf{r}_y|$ is useful for a general parameterization of a surface, but for just the flat plane, you don't always need a parameterization. You might use one like polar coordinates anyway, but integrals can be converted with a change of coordinates with a Jacobian factor, which for two variables is essentially $|\mathbf{r}_x \times \mathbf{r}_y|$.

Comment: Personally I prefer to think of parametrizing the *flat surface* by $\langle x,y,0 \rangle$ and then potentially change variables in that double integral (for example if the flat surface is a disk). But it is an interesting little exercise to show how the Jacobian determinant that you study in the "double integral" unit is identical to the factor $|\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v|$ that you get from a parametrization even when you bake the change of variables into the parametrization (e.g. $\mathbf{r}(r,\theta)=\langle r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta),0 \rangle$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formulation is the following. First it is true that when you parametrize a surface with $r(u,v)$, we have $d\mathbf{S} = |r_u \times r_v| dA$. Then $\mathbf{n} = \frac{r_u \times r_v}{|r_u \times r_v|}$ so $$\oint_C F\cdot dr = \iint_S (\nabla \times F) \cdot \mathbf{n} \,d\mathbf{S} = \iint_S (\nabla \times F) \cdot \frac{r_u \times r_v}{|r_u \times r_v|}|r_u \times r_v| dA = \iint_S (\nabla \times F) \cdot (r_u \times r_v) \,dA.$$ Now when your surface is on a coordinate plane, usually the $xy$-plane, then $r(u,v) = \langle u,v,0\rangle $ where $z = 0$ because the surface is on the $xy$-plane. Now $r_u \times r_v = \langle 1,0, 0\rangle \times \langle 0, 1, 0\rangle = \langle 0,0,1\rangle = \vec k$. What this is saying is the normal vector to a surface entirely in the $xy$-plane is the vector pointing up i.e. $\vec k$.

Now if $F = \langle P, Q, R\rangle$ then $\nabla \times F = \langle R_y - Q_z, P_z - R_x, Q_x - P_y\rangle$ so $$\iint_S (\nabla \times F)\cdot (r_u \times r_v)\,dA = \iint_S Q_x - P_y\, dA$$ which is exactly Green's Theorem.